# C++: Request more than 2GB of memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef uint64_t     Huge_num;  // 8 bytes
typedef Huge_num *   Huge_Arr; // Array of 8 byte elements

using namespace std;

// Function: Return a huge array
static Huge_Arr* requestMem(int n)
{
   cout << "requesting :" 
        << (sizeof(Huge_num)*n)/(1024*1024*1024) 
        << "GB" << endl;

   Huge_Arr *buff;
   try {
      buff = new Huge_Arr[n];
   }
   catch (bad_alloc){
      cout << "Not enough mem!" << endl; 
      exit(-1);
   }
   return buff;
}

// Main
int main(){
    for (int i=1; i< 10; i++){
         Huge_Arr *mem = requestMem(i*90000000);
         delete mem;
    }
}
```

For some reason malloc is only able to grab no more than 2GB of memory before throwing `bad_alloc()` error.

I understand that on 32-bit systems, the maximum address space is indeed on same order of 2GB.

But I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64, which *should* be able to handle larger memory requests, right?

EDIT: Turns out the answer was I was compiling with `g++ -std=c00x`, which is 32-bit? Not sure, either way I changed the Makefile to remove the `-std` flag and it compiled fine

Comment: Is your program *compiled* as a 64-bit program? It's possible you're compiling it as a 32-bit program, and thus are still limited to ~2GB of addressable space, despite it running on a 64-bit system.

Comment: You aren't using `malloc`, you are using `new`.  Your code fails to compile for problems completely unrelated to your question.  For example, you use `n` without defining it.  Can you actually write a small self contained program that actually compiles and actually demonstrates your problem?

Comment: C++ is using the same underlying system that C uses in this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463207

Comment: Oh, and check `sizeof(std::size_t)` from `<cstddef>` -- that is an easy way to see if you are compiling for a 64 or 32 bit system (assuming `char` is 8 bits, and the compiler isn't being silly).

Comment: Perhaps it cannot find a contiguous chunk of memory large enough.

Comment: where is "n" declared? What type is it?

Comment: So, on my system, I can allocate up to 8 in the loop [after I multiplied the large starting with 9 by ten, as it wasn't gettting to megabytes otherise]. That makes about 6GB. I have quite a few other things running on the system, so that may well be the limit for one contiguous memory allocation in my system.

Comment: @DrewDormann: C++ may (but may not) use the same underlying memory allocation as C see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/240308/14065

Comment: This code does not compile!

Comment: It should be able to find a chunk bigger than 2GB of virtual memory in a 64-bit environment. Here is a possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886802/heap-size-limitation-in-c

Comment: sorry guys, I wrote this example very fast 
@MatsPetersson -- sorry that's meant to be the function args -- edited

Comment: @Cornstalks -- how do I check? Is it in the Makefile?

Comment: @LokiAstari -- okay try it now, sorry about that

Comment: @Yakk -- okay I tried sizeof(std::size_t), and am getting 8 bytes.
What does this mean? Is it meant to be 16 on a 64-bit?

Comment: @tetris11: On a UNIX-y system, you can do `file <name-of-your-executable>` from the command line to see if it's 32 or 64 bit. `std::size_t` should be at least 8 in a 64-bit program, but it's also technically possible (as far as I know) for it to be 8 in a 32-bit program. Anyway, your program works fine for me on my system (I don't run out of memory), but I'm also compiling in 64-bits and have a ton of free RAM (and OS X may be overcommitting memory; I'm not sure).

Comment: @LokiAstari I remember that now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have increase your `swap space` size, it's possible to have more space for allocating, when `RAM` does not have enough memory, operating system grows `heap space` via swapping with `disk space`, so for this you might make changes in swap file size, this link explain it for best:

[All about Linux swap space](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8208-all-about-linux-swap-space)

Other best way is to turn `overcommitting` value **on**, if the `overcommitting` value sets to **off**, you can not allocate all of your memory on your system, with turn `overcommitting` value **on** you can allocate all of your memory space for your array.

for turn `overcommitting` value to **on**:

set `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to `0`

Comment: Okay that makes sense -- but how do I do that on Ubuntu/Debian?

Comment: But that's just swap space. As long as my RAM is big enough, paging need not occur. I have 32 GB RAM.

Answer (score 5):

`malloc` is allocating contiguous memory. The fact that you get a `badalloc` requesting 2 GB of memory doesn't necessarily mean that you have less than 2 GB of memory available, it can also mean that the memory available is fragmented. Try allocating smaller chunks if you want to test how much memory is available to be allocated on your system.

Comment: Thing is I've tried the same code on a 32GB 64-bit server and am getting the same results.
Surely such a system would have large bouts of unfragmented memory